# Modulo and Congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Little Fermats theorem states that

If $n$ is a prime number then $a^n \equiv a \mod{n}$

Equivalently

If $n$ is a prime number and $a$ is not divisible by $n$ then

$a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \mod{n}$

My doubt is

For any natural number $n$ if its correct that

$a^n \equiv a \mod{n}$

Then when i can also write it as

$a^{n-1} \equiv 1\mod{n}$

And when i cant write ?

Thanks in advance ........... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$ is not divisible by $p$, you can write $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$, just by dividing both sides by $a$.

If $a$ was divisible by $p$ then $a \pmod p$ would be $0$.

Comment: Consider this case :

$3^{561} \equiv 3 \mod{561}$ but $3^{560} \not\equiv 3 \mod{561}$

Comment: Fermat's theorem states that $3^{560} \equiv 1 \pmod{561}$, not $3 \pmod{561}$

Comment: im sry , i mean its false that $3^{560} \not\equiv 1 mod (561)$

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, it turns out $561$ isn't a prime so Fermat's Little Theorem does not apply.

Comment: Yeah . my doubt is when we can cancel a on both sides for any number $n$